# XML pode ser considerada um linguagem de programação?

Tags: xml, característica-linguagem

XML 
pode ser considerada um linguagem de programação? Ou um banco de dados?

Comment: não, assim como o html, o xml é uma linguagem de marcação.

Comment: Fechada como duplicata. Embora a outra pergunta seja sobre HTML, a resposta serve perfeitamente para XML também.

Comment: `<hate class="big bold">` ***XML pode ser considerado uma dor de cabeça.*** `</hate>`